# Looping through a SQL Server column using C# without a duplicate output

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple SQL Server database that has two columns, `States`  and `Capitals`. When I select button2, I would like to loop through the `States` column and randomly select a different state for a specified number of loops (the user will enter this number in another textbox) without selecting the same state twice.

The selected state must appear in textBox1. I've programmed textBox2 with a series of switch statement to capture the capitals. I'm having problems with seeing the same state more than once.

```
int count = 0;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count == Double.Parse(textBox3.Text) - 1) 
        this.Close();

    count++;

    String connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-N2F01G5\MRMARLEE;Initial Catalog=States_Capitals;Integrated Security=True";
    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM StatesandCapitals ORDER BY NEWID() ";

    String result = "";

    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 
    }

    textBox1.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: Why `ExecuteNonQuery()` _and_ `ExecuteScalar()`? You're running the query twice for no good reason!

Comment: New to programming. Recently retired from the military. Picking up coding as a hobby.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution to this problem is to grab as many as you want all in the same query. If they want 5 items, instead of selecting `TOP 1` five times in a loop, just select `TOP 5` once. Put the results into a List or array in memory you reference later.

Additionally, *don't pull the states for TextBox2 separately*. Get this all down to the one query that retrieves all the data you need. Generally speaking, the fewer round-trips to the DB, the better your application will perform.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need of `ExcecuteNonQuery()`.

`ORDER BY NEWID()` - The sample size is small (No. of states would typically be < 100?) so it may happen that even though the values of `NEWID()` are different each time you run the query, the `ORDER` may get the same `State`. Also, `NEWID()` has performance issues.

I suggest a C# + T-SQL approach as follows:

1. Declare a global instance of `Random` Class - `Random rnd = new Random();`
2. Get the total number of states - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StatesandCapitals` into a C# `int` variable (`intNumStates`) using `ExecuteScalar()`.
3. Now, get a random number between 1 and `intNumStates` and assign it to another C# int variable say `intRndStateNum` - `int intRndStateNum = rnd.Next(1, intNumStates + 1)`
4. Finally, run query using `ROW_NUMBER()` equating it with the random number:

   WITH RandomState AS 
   (
       SELECT States, RANDOM_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY States) AS RowNum
       FROM StatesandCapitals
   )
   SELECT States, RowNum
   FROM RandomState
   WHERE RowNum = ?

Replace `?` with `intRndStateNum` as a Parameter sent to the query (I am not writing this code assuming you know this).